# XPages jsonRpcService error message verbosity

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have a JSON-RPC service defined in an XPages application using the `<xe:jsonRpcService>` tag.

If a request to this server causes a JSON parsing error, a verbose error message is returned, example:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "text": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Error when parsing JSON stream",
    "type": "text",
    "data": "com.ibm.domino.services.ServiceException: \r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.services.rpc.RpcServiceEngine.renderService(RpcServiceEngine.java:82)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.services.HttpServiceEngine.processRequest(HttpServiceEngine.java:168)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rpc.UIJsonRpcService._processAjaxRequest(UIJsonRpcService.java:299)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rpc.UIJsonRpcService.processAjaxRequest(UIJsonRpcService.java:282)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.util.AjaxUtilEx$1.invokeContextCallback(AjaxUtilEx.java:194)\r\n\tat javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:862)\r\n\tat javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)\r\n\tat javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)\r\n\tat javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)\r\n\tat javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.invokeOnComponent(UIViewRootEx.java:1552)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.util.AjaxUtilEx.renderAjaxPartialLifecycle(AjaxUtilEx.java:188)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.renderAjaxPartial(FacesServletEx.java:249)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceAjaxPartialView(FacesServletEx.java:200)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceAjaxPartialViewSync(FacesServletEx.java:176)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:155)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:159)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)\r\nCaused by: com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonException: Error when parsing JSON stream\r\n\tat com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonParser.fromJson(JsonParser.java:86)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.services.rpc.RpcServiceEngine.renderService(RpcServiceEngine.java:55)\r\n\t... 29 more\r\nCaused by: com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.ParseException: Encountered \" <IDENTIFIER> \"x \"\" at line 1, column 39.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    \"false\" ...\r\n    \"null\" ...\r\n    \"true\" ...\r\n    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...\r\n    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...\r\n    <STRING_LITERAL> ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \r\n\tat com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.Json.generateParseException(Json.java:637)\r\n\tat com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.Json.jj_consume_token(Json.java:572)\r\n\tat com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.Json.literal(Json.java:230)\r\n\tat com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.Json.propertyNameAndValueList(Json.java:274)\r\n\tat com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.Json.objectLiteral(Json.java:244)\r\n\tat com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.parser.Json.parseJson(Json.java:383)\r\n\tat com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonParser.fromJson(JsonParser.java:84)\r\n\t... 30 more\r\n"
}
```

Is there anyway to disable this message? Or at least remove the stack trace in the `data`?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to turn off returning the data portion of the entire error message.